# 18.04.1 desktop: How to install the 'Fiona' voice that is present in the Festival TTS demo page

Tags: text-to-speech, festival

I want to dl/install the Fiona voice that is present on the [Festival TTS demo page](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/morevoices.html). I have searched around and found instructions on downloading and installing many other voices that are present in the demo page, but none has anything about this Fiona voice.
[image]

Please, if anyone knows more about this, I need your help.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.1

Answer (score 0):

They may not have completed that particular voice for distribution, or there could be a rights issue preventing distribution.  As noted on the web page you referred to, please consult the [FAQ](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/demofaq.html) (and) if that doesn't address your query, please mail [tts-demo@cstr.ed.ac.uk](http://mailto:tts-demo@cstr.ed.ac.uk).